# How do I configure phpmailer for my web host?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Here is my problem: I am trying to send mail from my site with phpmailer and, on the test version which uses my school server, no problem. I didn't even specify an email account and it works.

But when I transferred my site to my host (planetHoster) it was no longer working although a success message appeared.

Everything seems to be going as planned but I don't receive the email.
Here is my code:

```
  try{
                $this->mail->SMTPDebug = true;                      
                $this->mail->isSMTP();                                        
                $this->mail->Host       = 'mail.mywebsitearctest.yn.fr';           
                $this->mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                       
                $this->mail->Username   = '********@mywebsitearctest.yn.fr';             
                $this->mail->Password   = '************';                             
                $this->mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';         
                $this->mail->Port       = 465;                   
            
                $this->mail->setFrom($emailExpediteur);
                $this->mail->addAddress($emailDestinataire);            
                //$this->mail->addReplyTo($emailExpediteur);
            
                // Attachments
                $this->mail->addAttachment($file_location);          
            
                // Content
                $this->mail->isHTML(true);                                  
                $this->mail->Subject = 'Balance âgée';
                $this->mail->Body    = $emailContent;
                $this->mail->AltBody = 'Votre messagerie ne supporte pas le format html';
            
            if($this->mail->Send()){
                $message[].="Email envoyé avec succès";
                $type[].="success";
                $desc[].='Envoi mail';
            }
            else{
                $message[].="L'email n'a pas pu être envoyé";
                $type[].="error";
                $desc[].='Envoi mail';
            }
            
            }
            catch(Exception $e){
                echo "Erreur : erreur lors de l'envoi du mail";
            }
```

The debugging result does not seem to indicate an error, but it is far too long to copy here.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It always helps to read the docs. `$this->mail->SMTPDebug = true; ` will not show what the server is saying, which is what matters here; set it to `2`. It probably won't help though as your error checking looks OK, so the first thing I'd check is your spam folder.

Comment: So I tried setting SMTPDebug to 2. It's the same thing with a few lines. Of course I checked for spam, but nothing.

Comment: If you’re really getting a `250 OK` after submitting your message, the problem is not in your code. Try sending via a different server, talk to your email host.

Comment: I actually have the message 250 OK, so I will contact my host. Thank you.

Comment: Small precision, when I send an email to the dedicated address, it works, but from the interface of this address (at my host) the sending does not work.

Comment: If the only thing changing is the source IP, that sounds like an SPF problem.